# Avoiding mix of certain arguments to script

Tags: perl, arguments, flags, getopt-long

I have a script which can get tens of arguments/flags using `Getopt::Long`.
Certain flags are not allowed to be mixed, such as: `--linux --unix` are not allowed to be supplied together.  I know I can check using an `if` statement.  Is there is a cleaner and nicer way to do that?

`if` blocks can get ugly if I don't want to allow many combinations of flags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does not seem that [Getopt::Long](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html) has such a feature, and nothing sticks out after a quick [search of CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=getopt&mode=all).  However, if you can use a hash to store your options, creating your own function doesn't seem too ugly:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Getopt::Long;

my %opts;
GetOptions(\%opts, qw(
    linux
    unix
    help
)) or die;

mutex(qw(linux unix));

sub mutex {
    my @args = @_;
    my $cnt = 0;
    for (@args) {
        $cnt++ if exists $opts{$_};
        die "Error: these options are mutually exclusive: @args" if $cnt > 1;
    }
}
```

This also scales to more than 2 options:

```
mutex(qw(linux unix windoze));
```